# Hide Slider on Post Type Page

Tags: custom-post-types, conditional-tags

If users enter a code on the homepage and that code is valid they will be sent to a post type page where a profile is shown. The issue is that somehow the homepage slider is shown on that profile page too. Somehow it is loaded as well and I do not want that. I tried to unload it using a conditional, but that does not seem to work. Here is the homepage code:

```
    <?php get_header(); ?>
    <div id="wrapper2nd">
        <div class="content">
        <div id="slider">
            <ul>        
            <?php
            //if ( 'viewprofile' !== get_post_type() ) {
        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'slider', 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        ?>      
                <li>
                    <div class="alingRight">
                        <?php
                        the_content();
                        echo the_post_thumbnail();
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </li>



    <?php   endwhile;   
    //}
    ?>  
            </ul>
        </div>    <div class="container">
                    <form action="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>?post_type=viewprofile" method="post">
                    <span><?php _e('If you received a Card,</br> enter the code here:', 'textdomain');?></span><input name="myaccesskey" type="text" class="inputBox" /><input type="submit" value="<?php _e('Go', 'textdomain');?>" class="go" />
                    </form>
              </div>
              <div class="clr"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
 <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And here is the majority of the profile view page:

```
<?php
        if(empty($_REQUEST['myaccesskey'])){

                echo "<script>
                    location.replace('".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."'); 
                    </script>";
        }else{
                global $wpdb;
        $getId = null;
        $getCode = $_POST['myaccesskey'];
    $querystr = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT user_id FROM wp_x_usermeta WHERE meta_key='myaccesskey' AND meta_value='%s'",$getCode); 
                $querystrChecking = mysql_query($querystr);
                if(mysql_num_rows($querystrChecking)<=0){
                    echo "<script>
                    location.replace('".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."'); 
                    </script>";
                }
        elseif ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($querystrChecking)) {
            $getId = $row['user_id'];
        }
                $uploads = wp_upload_dir(); 
            //
        }
        ?>
    <?php get_header(); ?>
    <div id="wrapper2nd" class="inner">
        <div class="content" id="inner">

        <h1>PROFILE</h1>
        <div id="profileView">
            <div class="alignLeft">
             <strong><?php _e('Name:', 'textdomain');?></strong> <?php the_author_meta( 'first_name', $getId ); ?>   <?php the_author_meta( 'last_name', $getId); ?><br />
              <strong><?php _e('Nick Name:', 'textdomain');?></strong> <?php the_author_meta( 'nickname', $getId ); ?><br />
              <strong><?php _e('Age:', 'textdomain');?></strong><?php get_the_author_meta( 'dateofbirth', $getId );?><br />

            <?=get_the_author_meta( 'myfavouritelinks', $getId );?>

          </div>
             <div class="alignRight">
                <div class="left"><i><?php _e('About Me:', 'soodba');?></i>
                    <p> <?=the_author_meta( 'description', $getId); ?></p>
                </div>
                <div class="right">
                    <?php if(get_the_author_meta( 'userphoto_thumb_file', $getId )!=""){?>
                        <img src="<?=$uploads['baseurl'];?>/thumbs/<?=get_the_author_meta( 'userphoto_thumb_file', $getId );?>" />
                    <?php }?>
                <a href="#" class="allpic"><?php _e('see all pictures', 'textdomain');?></a>
                </div>
                <div class="clr"></div>
                <div class="contact"><strong><?php _e('Contact information:', 'textdomain');?></strong> <?= get_the_author_meta('user_email', $getId );?></div>
             </div>
             <div class="clr"></div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>

     <?php if ( is_active_sidebar('inner')): ?>
    <div id="wrapper3rd">
      <div id="innerSidebarContent">
     <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'inner' ); ?>

      </div>
    </div>
    <?php endif; // end sidebar widget area ?>
 <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I tried other conditionals such as `if (is_page() || is_front_page())`, but the slider is still loaded on the profile page underneath the `get_the_author_meta` details as I guess it is part of the front page still???. Any ideas how to fix this?

**Update**

It seems that profile view is loaded as a substring - url http://www.domain.com/?post_type=viewprofile  - of index.php. I mean, the profile page seems to be an addition of the index, while it should be a separate page. Somehow my coding is incorrectly loading index.php code

**Update 2**

I gave the custom post a slug using:

```
register_post_type('profile', array(
    'label' => __('Profile'),
    'singular_label' => __('Profile'),
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => false, // UI in admin panel
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'rewrite' => array("slug" => "user-profile"), // Permalinks format
    'supports' => array('title','author')
));
```

and now the conditional does work. The slider is not loaded. But the profileviewpage code is not yet either.

Comment: Added some answers to questions I found solutions for and accepted some answers when they were correct. Now let's crack this one..

Comment: cool mate - hope my answer helps  -  update me if you need additional help - would try my best  :)

Answer (score 1):

why not make author.php page where you can design it and load stuff as you wish?
do you have that?

Anyhow try to wrap the entire div class=slider with this since maybe
your home page is index.php and not a page template... :

```
<?php if(is_home() || is_front_page()) { ?>

<div class="slider">
All the slider stuff here..
</div>

<?php } else } ?>

i am not the homepage!

<?php } ?>
```

.
Hope this helps..
Cheers, Sagive

Comment: Well, I guess the profile page is an author page with several author_meta fields so I could have done that too. Not sure if I can migrate all easily to a public author page and keep the access code rule running. Going to try your conditional tag now.